# Firebug showing eval scripts on one line

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

When loading a JavaScript block via Ajax, the response is returned ok, but when viewing it in the code in Firebug (1.9.1) in the Script tab, it appears without any newlines. It's extremely difficult or impossible to set breakpoints anywhere.

Is there a way to get Firebug to preserve the newlines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix for Chrome.

Simply add the following snippet to where you want to debug:

```
try{ throw Error() } catch(e) {}
```

and click the "Pause on all Exceptions" button in the Chrome Scripts console tab. Then simply hit F8 until you reach your try block.

Works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but Chrome's developer tools unobfuscator may do what you want (http://www.sagarganatra.com/2011/06/de-obfuscating-javascript-code-in.html).

However, if you load in your script blocks by adding a script tag to the page and changing its source to point to the relevant script file the eval function isn't used and firebug should display the script with line breaks included.